# What are some examples of bad pairs $(A,X)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

A good pair $(A,X)$ is such that $A\subset X$ and there is a neighborhood deformation retract of A in X. What are some examples of bad pairs? I think $(A,I)$ where $A = ${$0,1,1/2,1/3...$} is a bad pair (is it?). Are there any other examples?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "What are some examples of bad pairs $(A,X)$?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath I conjecture that OP has encountered the mathematical terminology "bad" only in this context and therefore might have thought the title was a full description. (The tags are also helpful in this regard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when $X$ is locally connected, but $A$ is not, it will be a bad pair. This covers your example and many many more, e.g. Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}$, comb space in $\mathbb{R}^2$, etc.